# Get array size for use in for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, maze

I'm trying to get the size of my tiles array so it can be used in the for loop below. However, when compiling, it is showing that .size() is experimental in C++ 2011. What would be the best way to get the size in relation to this loop which checks each tile for the 'E' character? I'm using array instead of a vector so please assist me with arrays.

```
void Floor::placePlayer()
{
    bool foundEntry = false;
    int entryX;
    int entryY;

    for (int x = 0; x < tiles.size() && !foundEntry; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < tiles[x].size() && !foundEntry; y++)
        {
            if (tiles[x][y] == 'E')
            {
                player.set_position (x,y);
                tiles[x][y] = 'P';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also this is my array from the header:

```
const static int ROWS = 20;
const static int COLS = 30;
char tiles[ROWS][COLS];
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since you have already hardcoded the values as `const`, why not just use `ROWS` and `COLS`?

Comment: Well the values are coming from a txt file, but the ROWS and COLS are limited to 20 and 30 respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use your `const static int` used to create the array ?

```
void Floor::placePlayer()
{
    bool foundEntry = false;
    int entryX;
    int entryY;

    for (int x = 0; x < ROWS && !foundEntry; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < COLS && !foundEntry; y++)
        {
            if (tiles[x][y] == 'E')
            {
                player.set_position (x,y);
                tiles[x][y] = 'P';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so `const static int ROWS = 20` and cols would need to now be public then right. Also My rows and columns are getting filled from a maze txt file so would your code still be valid? In order to fix a compiler error a changed `const int ROWS = 20 ` and `const int COLS = 30;` to `const static int ROWS...` but perhaps this is incorrect?

Comment: If the "real" valued of `ROWS` and `COLS` are coming from a txt file, you should have stored them somewhere. Use this stored value. Because you are working with C arrays, there is no standard way to retrieve the size.

Comment: Okay, well they are store in my `char tiles[ROWS][COLS]` array so I think what you suggested should work.

Comment: Don't forget to initialize `tiles`.

Comment: Above the for loops you mean? So like `char tiles[ROWS][COLS];` right above my loops or does the initializer look different?

Comment: consider using `std::array< std::array<char, COLS>, ROWS> tiles;` as the array type. Then you can use `.size()` function and also `begin()` and `end()` for making iterator pairs instead of using an index counter.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you can use the following function to give you the number of elements in a C-style array:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t lengthof( T (&arr)[N] )  { return N; }
```

Then the loops would be:

```
for (size_t x = 0; x < lengthof(tiles) && !foundEntry; x++)

    for (size_t y = 0; y < lengthof(tiles[x]) && !foundEntry; y++)
```

This is safer than hardcoding values because that way, if you later changed the size of your array, your loops would begin to silently access the wrong number of elements.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind. All the maze floors are 20x30 but this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

> for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(tiles)/sizeof(char*) && !foundEntry; x++)

and

> for (int y = 0; y < sizeof(tiles[x])/sizeof(char) && !foundEntry; y++)

Comment: There is no need to do that since it will return the allocated size. The OP expects the "real" size.

Comment: What do you think `sizeof(char *)` has to do with anything? There are no pointers to `char` here.

Comment: You meant `sizeof tiles / sizeof tiles[0]`, and `sizeof tiles[x] / sizeof tiles[x][0]`. Which would work.

Comment: your offer if not save is the array is empty, so I have to use direct type sizeof. sizeof(char*) is the same as sizeof of any array